# Progressive Web App in different devices on local network

Tags: android, ios, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, local-network

We are starting to develop a Web App that can work in different devices and still be connected between them even if there is no internet connection, but a working local network.

We need to send notifications between devices in the same local network with no internet, and we would really like to develop a PWA, if not possible work with native mobile apps.

If anybody knows how to make Service Workers work this way, we would appreciate it.

UPDATE:
We found this information:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network

We think that maybe using UDP we can manage to make it work, but we are not sure...